# Why am I getting a segmentation fault at the end of the function (C)?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, getopt

I am getting a segmentation fault at the end of readFirst().  If I put in a print statement to check sometimes the print statement doesn't appear.  The code compiles, but when I run it, it just prints the file like it is supposed to, then it gives me the fault at the return statement.  I have no idea what the problem is and no idea how to fix it.

```
int readFirst(FILE *file){
    int c;
    int linecount = 0;
    int newLineCounter = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        if(c == '\n'){
            newLineCounter++;
        }
            linecount++;
    }
    file = file + '\0';
    printf("check 3");
    //printf("\n");

    printf("%i",newLineCounter);
    return newLineCounter;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *infile = NULL;
    char *outfile = NULL;
    FILE *file = stdin;
    FILE *text = stdout;
    char ch[200];
    int iFlag = 0;
    int oFlag = 0;
    char *iValue = NULL;
    int index;
    int i;

    opterr = 0;

    while ((i = getopt (argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 'i':
                iFlag = 1;
            infile = optarg;
                break;
            case 'o':
            oFlag = 1;
                outfile = optarg;
                break;
            case '?':
                if(optopt == 'i') {
                fprintf(stderr, "Missing mandatory input option\n");
            } else if (optopt == 'o') {
                fprintf(stderr, "Missing mandatory input option\n");
                } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option received\n");
                }
            break;
            }
    }

    if (infile){
        file = fopen(infile, "r");
        if (file == NULL){
            //printf("cannot open input file \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        //fprintf(file,"%s", infile);
        //fprintf(file,"%s", infile);

    }
    printf("check 1");
    int lines;
    lines = readFirst(file);
    printf("check 2");
    printf("%i", lines);

    char labels [lines][6];

    int c;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int curCol = 0;
    int flag = 0;


    for(lineCount = 0; i < lines; lineCount++){
        for(curCol = 0; i < 6; curCol++){
            labels[lineCount][curCol] = ' ';
        }
    }

    while(lineCount < lines && (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
        if(flag != 0){
            if(c != ' ' || c != '\t'){
                labels[lineCount][curCol] = c;
                curCol++;
            }else {
                curCol = 0;
                flag = 0;
            }
        }

        if(c == '\n'){
            flag = 1;
            lineCount++;
        }
    }


    printf("%i", lineCount);

    for(lineCount = 0; i < lines; lineCount++){
        for(curCol = 0; i < 6; curCol++){
            printf("%c",labels[lineCount][curCol]);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: what is `file = file + '\0';` supposed to do?

Comment: @pm100 yeah I forgot to delete that but it's not the issue.  The problem occurred before I added that and is still occurring after I took it out.

Comment: put \n on the end of all your tracing printfs, thet will ensure they get output correctly so you can see where u got up to

Comment: also, compile with -g and run under gdb, that will show you where it goes bang

Comment: @pm100 good idea.  the segmentation fault is happening right at the return statement because the print statements before it worked fine once I added a new line char

Comment: Note that you should ensure that `printf()` statements used for 'got here' diagnostics at minimum end with a newline.  You might even want/need to use `fflush(stdout)`.  If you don't do that, the output can sit in a buffer and not be displayed even after the program crashes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here, in the inner loop

```
for(lineCount = 0; i < lines; lineCount++){
    for(curCol = 0; i < 6; curCol++){
        printf("%c",labels[lineCount][curCol]);
    }
}
```

The variable i never gets updated in that loop, so both loops will run forever, causing an out of bounds array access of labels.

Comment: that is an error, thanks for letting me know, but it isn't causing the segmentation fault.  It occurs much earlier than that

Comment: wait never mind, that was the issue! you are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: You should show the fix in the answer. Change `i < lines` to `lineCount < lines`.

Comment: And the second loop should use `curCol < 6`.